# Detect the same two sentences

Tags: spelling, grammar

In TeXStudio, spelling and grammar checks seem unable to detect the same two sentences written in a paragraph or document. Obviously, popular grammar solutions didn't catch this spelling mistake either. Is there any other way to fix this situation?
For example:

> ... software and converted to vectors. It was seen that some instances in the data set contained Turkish characters and some did not. It was seen that some instances in the data set contained Turkish characters and some did not. Essentially, all ...

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I'm not sure this is a TeX question as much as an editor question.  Furthermore, there are numerous examples in poetic prose where whole-line phrases are repeated for impact.  It might be tough to instruct an editor how to tell the difference. Example: "Caged Bird" by Maya Angelou, where the whole verse, "The caged bird sings
with fearful trill
of the things unknown
but longed for still
and his tune is heard
on the distant hill for the caged bird
sings of freedom" is repeated.

Comment: I don't use TeXStudio myself but if it supports regular expression search with backreferences, then you can search for a sentence-like expression (for example capital letter followed by multiple not-a-dot followed by a dot) which occurs twice in a row.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks for the nice welcome. Especially when converting a document written in Word to .TEX format, copy and paste is often done. While doing this, you can copy a sentence twice. This is actually what happened to me. I think this problem is a problem for this type of process in general. Even "Google Docs" could not detect it. I asked this question to find out if there is a custom solution for TEX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To illustrate my comment: in most editors you can do regular expression search, probably this is also possible in TeXStudio. Use for example the following expression:

```
([A-Z][^.]+\.) \1
```

This means:

`(` start group 1, consisting of

`[A-Z]` capital letter, followed by

`[^.]+` 1 or more characters that are not a dot, followed by

`\.` a dot,

`)` end group 1,

then a space,

`\1` and then the sequence that matched group 1 again.

Illustration in gEdit:

[image]

Note: obviously you can make the expression much smarter to include other types of sentences, for example without a space in between or that end with something else than a dot.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. It didn't work on TexStudio. I downloaded the Windows version of "gEdit" and installed it. I edited it as in the screenshot you sent. But that didn't work either.

Comment: @Erkan that is strange. Did you make sure to check the 'Regular expression' checkbox? What happens when you search without the `\1` at the end (that should find just a single sentence)?

Comment: @Marjin I saved the file as .tex. The last `\1` is required. Without it it doesn't work. But just as you say `.` can find sentences ending with. Can be improved.

Comment: @Erkan I'm not sure I understand your comment. Does this mean that the example that I gave in the answer works for you as well? Because earlier you said that it did not work. Regarding the `\1`: it is required, I asked you to try without it to make sure that the regular expression search itself works, which is easier to see with a simpler example (although the simpler example without the `\1` does not find a repeated sentence, it just finds any sentence).

Comment: @Erkan for the improvements: there are many possibilities with regular expressions, but that is not really the topic of the site here, so I didn't get into much detail but I just gave a proof of concept. However, you will be able to find many tutorials on regular expressions around the internet, from which you can learn to create complex patterns.

Comment: I didn't understand why it didn't work before. Is it because I didn't save it as ".tex"? I thought and tried. It works even if you don't save it. Now it works. As you mentioned, suitable for development. [There is a lot of information](http://www.endmemo.com/r/gsub.php). That was enough for me. Thank you for your help.